# Extend R 3D array vertically

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have an array of size c(1,n,m). I would like to extend the array vertically by repeating the first row k times. So I will have an array of size c(k,n,m). For example:

```
x  <- array(1:6, c(1,3,2))
```

then if k is 3, I'd like the expanded array to be

```
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3


, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    4    5    6
```

I am currently performing this using aperm within a for loop, but it is very slow. Because the dimensions of my real problem is about 100*100*40000

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replicate` inside `apply` and fix the `dim` after

```
k <- 3
out <- apply(x, 3, replicate, n = k)
dim(out) <- dim(x)*c(k, 1, 1)
aperm(out, c(2, 1, 3))

# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# [3,]    1    2    3
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    5    6
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    4    5    6
```

Or (same result)

```
k <- 3
out <- apply(x, 3, function(x) do.call(rbind, replicate(k, x, simp = F)))
dim(out) <- dim(x)*c(k, 1, 1)
out
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but each page seems to be transposed, which is slightly different to my intended output

Comment: I couldn't get the first solution to work - but the second solution works very well. Thanks. Although it still has performance issues.

Comment: I found the following is faster, but not as neat: out <- t(matrix(rep(as.vector(x), k), nrow= dim(x)[2]*dim(x)[3], ncol= k))
dim(out) <- c(k,1,1)*dim(x)

Comment: I like that one better. You should post it and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks IceCreamToucan,

I couldn't get the first solution to work - but the second solution works very well. Thanks. Although it still has performance issues

I modified your original solution as follows. It is faster, but not as neat:

```
out <- t(matrix(rep(as.vector(x), k), nrow= dim(x)[2]*dim(x)[3], ncol= k)) 

dim(out) <- c(k,1,1)*dim(x)
```